# VB6 References needed to be added to create a datable please

Tags: vb6

I am able to have a recordset. But back to VB6 from a long time ago. I desperately need to get the references to be able to create a table to use in code which will then take the records and display that to excel which is already written and works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for VB6 product documentation, the first place to look would be the installation CD, but I found the following on MSDN.

Here is the documentation for VB6 from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576613.aspx

Here is the documentation of the ADO Data Control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231217%28v=VS.60%29.aspx

Here is general information about accessing data in VB6:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261277%28v=VS.60%29.aspx